# Unable to upload tiff images in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, tiff

Tried to upload .tiff images using Laravel. used intervention/image for the image upload.
it's not worked.shows this message.
Unsupported image type image/tiff. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP or WebP files.

```
public function uploadmage($catId,$file)
    {
        $diskName = 'public';
        $disk = Storage::disk($diskName);
        $path = $file->store('uploads/catalog/' . $catId, $diskName);
        $fileName = basename($path);

        $image['img_name'] = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $destinationPath = storage_path('app/public/uploads/catalog/' . $catId);
        $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());

        $img->resizeCanvas($dimension, '450', 'center', false, '#FFFFFF');

        $img->save($destinationPath . '/' . $image['img_name']);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It clearly says that gd driver does not support tiff format. Maybe you should use Imagick driver. [Here](https://image.intervention.io/v2/introduction/configuration) shows how to do it.